# Database logon failed when connecting crystal report with asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I made a crystal report in asp.net. My database is MS-Access 2007. I connect the report with database using dataset. Now when I execute the program it gives the error "Database logon failed".

How to solve this problem ...

Please help..

Regards
Abhishek

Comment: can you show the generated `asp` code for dataset

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how can you connect with dataset. From your post what i assume is that you probably are populating a dataset and using this dataset for databinding with the report.

In that case you should provide a name to your table in the dataset.

The name of the table in the dataset must exactly match the the table or view on which the report is designed. Otherwise Crystal report will not be able to find it.

```
ds.Tables[0].Name="yourTableorViewNameHere";
```

also you need to provide login info to your report.

```
private void myLogonInfo(CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument myReport)
{
    TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

    string server = "MyServer";
    string userID = "User1";
    string passwd = "MyPw";
    string DBNAME = "MyDB";

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= myReport.Database.Tables.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = server;
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = userID;
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = passwd;
        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = DBNAME;
        myReport.Database.Tables[i].ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

And here is the code to initialize the report

```
private void ShowRep(dataset ds)
{
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("MyReport.rpt"));

//either assign the dataset to the report here
rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);

//or provide the login details
//myLogonInfo(rptDoc);

//assign record filtering here
//rptDoc.RecordSelectionFormula = "{RDNewCollections.tdate}>=" + GetCrystalDate(ffdt.Text) ;

// set some report parameters
rptDoc.SetParameterValue(0, ffdt.Text);
rptDoc.SetParameterValue(1, tdt.Text);

//finally assign the report to the reportviewer
Crv.ReportSource = rptDoc;

}
```

You can call this from page load.

If you are using datasets then no need to pass logonifo. If you are not using dataset then you must call logoninfo.

Comment: I didn't write any code to connect report to the dataset. Also there is no userid and password in my access database. where to write ds.Tables[0].Name="yourTableorViewNameHere" (in formload???)...Also Do I have to give login info for each and every record????

Comment: You can find the examples in your C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Crystal Reports\Samples\En\Code folder

Answer (score 0):

```
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();

rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report/[your-report].rpt"));
rptDoc.SetParameterValue(0, [your-param]);
rptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon(username, password); --> this will solve your issue
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback...

Comment: Well my explanation is, when you calling your report, it have to be supplied with username and password if its required authentication to connect with the db, it is self explanatory error message.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Open your db file with Access then go to option then Client.

After that it will work.